# var_dump() the save() function in cakephp not showing all the fields

Tags: mysql, cakephp, insert, save

I am trying to save some data to my table `gal_photographers`. Though my table structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gal_photographers` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gal_provider_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `starting_month` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '01',
  `starting_year` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2010',
  `starting_package_wedding` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `starting_package_prewedding` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `starting_package_studio` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `willing_to_travel` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `candid_photography` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `traditional_photography` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pre-wedding` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `portraiture` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `portfolios` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location_shoots` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `videography` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `awards1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `awards2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `awards3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `video_title1` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `video_link1` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `video_title2` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `video_link2` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `video_title3` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `video_link3` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=455 ;
```

And I am trying to save with :

```
$sv = $this->GalPhotographer->save();
var_dump($sv);
if($sv) {
    echo 'SUCCESS';
}else{ echo 'NO SUCCESS !'; 
}
```

But the above `save()` is not inserting all the data. Moreover the `var_dump($sv)` shows :

```
array (size=1)
  'GalPhotographer' => 
    array (size=10)
      'starting_month' => string '01' (length=2)
      'starting_year' => string '2010' (length=4)
      'willing_to_travel' => string '0' (length=1)
      'candid_photography' => string '0' (length=1)
      'traditional_photography' => string '0' (length=1)
      'pre-wedding' => string '0' (length=1)
      'portraiture' => string '0' (length=1)
      'portfolios' => string '0' (length=1)
      'location_shoots' => string '0' (length=1)
      'videography' => string '0' (length=1)
```

And of course, I am getting a `SUCCESS` message though all my data are not inserting !

Comment: What are those values?

Comment: How does the model look like? Do you have field validations?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear where you're trying to get the data from. I'm guessing it should come from a view with a form, is the form submitting correctly?

What the save() actually saves right now are the default values you have defined in your sql commands.

Create a form with the [Cakes Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) and with *all* the fields for the Model and make it submit to the appropriate action. The actions should probably look something like follows...

```
public function add($gal_provider_id = null) {
    if (!$gal_provider_id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Gal Provider'));
    }
    $this->set('provider', $gal_provider_id);
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $this->GalPhotographer->create();
        if ($this->GalPhotographer->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Success!'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('No success!'));
        }
    }
}

public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid GalPhotographer'));
    }
    $phtgrpher = $this->GalPhotographer->findById($id);
    if (!$phtgrpher) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid GalPhotographer'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $this->GalPhotographer->create();
        if ($this->GalPhotographer->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Success!'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('No success!'));
        }
    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $phtgrpher;
    }
}
```